# Is an ability score improvement better than crossbow expert in combination with extra attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranger

i am making a level 5 ranger with 16 dex, a normal longbow shot would be:

1d8 + 3 (dex) * 2(extra attack)

I was wondering if my level 4 trait should be crossbow expert or a ASI.

with crossbow expert i can use the heavy crossbow with extra attack:

1d10 + 3 * 2

with ASI and a longbow:

1d8 + 4 * 2

what choice would be better for DPR?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134058/45088

Comment: Your calculation is wrong - you do not add your proficiency score to your damage roll, only to the attack.

Comment: Moreover, your proficiency bonus for level 4 is +2, not +3

Answer (score -2):

### Crossbow expert is the best choice

Crossbow expert lets you ignore the loading property, so you can fire twice (Attack + extra attack) PLUS your bonus action, for a total of 3 times. Not just twice as per your question.

As per the answer in the link provided by [L0neGamer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134049/when-is-2-dex-better-than-crossbow-expert/134058#134058) having an extra attack is always better.

The question to ask yourself is: Do you always have a bonus action available to use with the extra attack?

Comment: This would be better if you'd support this by comparing the two, not just assert the positives of one of the options.

Comment: Crossbow Expert feat allows you to attack with your bonus action only using a hand crossbow, and only after attacking with a one-handed weapon. So no heavy crossbows.