# Heavy Crossbow vs (unmodded) 5th level Eldritch Blast, which would be more reliable?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, ranged-attack

Which of these two would be more reliable at least in terms of consistently dealing damage?

I'm not going to take the Agonizing Blast Invocation because I'm planning to take other Invocations, so I won't get the +CHA mods on the EB's. I have 14 DEX so the Crossbow would deal 1d10+2 damage. Now, obviously 5th level EB would have out damage the Crossbow on a high roll, but on the lowest roll, EB would deal 2 damage and the Crossbow would deal 3.

There's also the fact that EB has more mods at least in terms of being able to actually hit (I have 18 CHA so +4 to hit mods, NOT including proficiency), but I could also get a Pact Weapon heavy crossbow with the Improved Pact Weapon Invocation. With that, it becomes more accurate and more damaging, but it still doesn't measure up to the maximum roll of 5th level EB, but I think it would deal much more consistent damage.

Taking everything I mentioned above into account, what is statistically the more consistent damage dealer between a Heavy Crossbow (which I have proficiency with due to Hex Warrior and an additional +2 from 14 DEX), or a 5th level Eldritch blast (which is helped by 18 CHA which gives it +4 to hit, not yet counting the proficiency)?

And what is statistically the more consistent damage dealer between a Pact weapon Heavy Crossbow (+1 to attack and damage rolls and being a Pact Weapon gives it +5 to both attack and damage rolls in total without proficiency) vs the 5th level EB I mentioned above?

Comment: I'm confused: if you "could get the Improved Pact Weapon invocation," why couldn't you take Agonizing Blast in that invocation's place?

Comment: One note that might worth to add is if you are going to face lot's of situation where magic is impossible. Tied down, muted, anti magic field ?

Comment: @Franck Tied down you can't shoot a heavy crossbow either.

Comment: @Andras Probably because Improved Pact Weapon becomes available at 3rd level, whereas one has to wait until 5th for Thirsting Blade.

Comment: @András Thirsting Blade wouldn't help with a crossbow anyway, since nothing in the Warlock removes the Loading feature. The shortbow option should be able to fire twice per turn if you have Thirsting Blade, but not the crossbow.

Comment: @Andras At risk of these comments getting deleted as "extended discussion," I'll surmise that OP is gunning hard for invocations optimal for a Hexblade and blade pact build, and so doesn't want to give up Improved Pact Weapon. That's the only reason I can see for posing this question in the first place. (Otherwise, why *not* take Agonizing Blast?)

Comment: @Andras And I'll further surmise that OP asked about heavy crossbow because the damage die is comparable to *eldritch blast*, whereas the die for both longbow and shortbow is smaller.

Comment: @screamline OP could (should) replace some other invocation by Thirsting Blade, if IPW is so impoertant.

Comment: @András I don't see this question as [warranting a frame challenge answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3318/43484), but if you do, you're welcome to post one... which I now see you already did.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### A Misconception that needs to be cleared up

Hex Warrior lets you use Charisma instead of the normal modifier for either your Hex weapon, or your Pact weapon. If you were to take the *Improved Pact Weapon* invocation, you'd be able to use +CHA with your crossbow instead of +DEX. So that alters the calculations somewhat.

## Levels 5-10: Eldritch Blast is better (but Crossbows can be made to be better)

The DPR on the double blast is always going to exceed the DPR of a single crossbow bolt, even after being boosted with *Improved Pact Weapon*. There's not really any getting around that. The other posts have already gone into the math explaining why.

However.

Taking the *Crossbow Expert* feat will (until level 11) make Crossbows reign supreme. This is because the *Crossbow Expert* feat removes the attack limitation on crossbows, meaning you'll be able to attack twice a turn (with Thirsting Blade), causing the DPR on the crossbow to rocket upwards, even exceeding that of Agonizing Blast.

Here's a table of DPR values, against various ACs of enemies you might fight:

\begin{array}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
                           & \text{AC 0}    & \text{AC 14}   & \text{AC 16}   & \text{AC 18}   & \text{AC 20}   & \text{AC 26}  \\ \hline
\text{Eldritch Blast x2}          & 11.000 & 8.250  & 7.150  & 6.050  & 4.950  & 1.650 \\ \hline
\text{Agonizing Blast x2}         & 18.600 & 13.850 & 11.950 & 10.050 & 8.150  & 2.450 \\ \hline
\text{Crossbow x1 (uses DEX)}               & 7.400  & 4.775  & 4.025  & 3.275  & 2.525  & 0.650 \\ \hline
\text{Crossbow x1 (IPW)}          & 10.250 & 8.150  & 7.100  & 6.050  & 5.000  & 1.850 \\ \hline
\text{Crossbow x2 (Expert / TB)}       & 14.800 & 9.550  & 8.050  & 6.550  & 5.050  & 1.300 \\ \hline
\text{Crossbow x2 (IPW / Expert / TB)} & 20.500 & 16.300 & 14.200 & 12.100 & 10.000 & 3.700 \\ \hline
\end{array}

<sup>[detailed statistical breakdown here](https://gist.github.com/Xirema/845fc7f30efbd43c1bcb3b1baedbfc03)</sup>

In the last row, you can see that against all AC levels, the DPR of taking the *Improved Pact Weapon* and *Thirsting Blade* invocations, and the *Crossbow Expert* feat, will exceed the DPR of even *Agonizing Blast* on an *Eldritch Blast*.

So between levels 5 and 10, (which is where most play occurs!) your DPR with a crossbow can be better than your DPR with Eldritch Blast, assuming you take the right invocations and feat.

## Level 11: Agonizing Blast is best

At level 11, the third Eldritch Blast improves the DPR by a lot, bringing the DPR ahead of where the Crossbow is at for this level. The regular Eldritch Blast isn't competitive at this level.

## Levels 12-16: Crossbows (barely) come out ahead again

The introduction of the *Lifedrinker* invocation (+CHA to pact weapon damage... again) will set things *just barely* back in the favor of the Crossbow:

\begin{array}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
                           & \text{AC 0}    & \text{AC 14}   & \text{AC 16}   & \text{AC 18}   & \text{AC 20}   & \text{AC 26}  \\ \hline
\text{Eldritch Blast x3}                           & 16.500 & 14.025 & 12.375 & 10.725 & 9.075  & 4.125 \\ \hline
\text{Agonizing Blast x3}                          & 30.750 & 26.025 & 22.875 & 19.725 & 16.575 & 7.125 \\ \hline
\text{IPW / Expert / TB / LD Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 28.600 & 25.300 & 22.000 & 18.700 & 8.800 \\ \hline
\end{array}

<sup>[detailed statistical breakdown here](https://gist.github.com/Xirema/bbaa72a7758286746255c33fab368109)</sup>

## Level 17: Agonizing Blast is best

Finally, with 4 attacks, Agonizing Blast will get up to a DPR of [41|38.9|34.7|30.5|26.3|13.7], which will be better than the (improved) DPR values that the Crossbow gets, stuck at 2 attacks, with [31.9|31.9|28.6|25.3|22.0|12.1].

So realistically, which combo you go with depends on what level of play your campaign will be at. If you actually expect to make it all the way to level 17+, then focus on Eldritch Blast and ignore the Crossbow feat + invocations. If you plan to never play past 16, then get the Crossbow feat and take invocations improving the Crossbow.

Note that getting the Crossbow this high *does* involve taking a feat and several invocations; if you'd rather dedicate those slots to other features, the *Agonizing Blast* setup only requires the one Invocation, and very little else. So in terms of economical builds, *Agonizing Blast* is easier to build around.

Comment: First time I grasped that the cha bonus stacks since it is from two different sources ... +1 and love the tables.

Comment: I think that a hand crossbow with the crossbow expert feat comes out ahead at all levels.

Comment: @goodguy5 Yeah, I'm running the numbers on it right now.

Comment: @András If you lose the extra CHA to the Crossbow Expert feat, the Heavy Crossbow becomes *exactly* equal to Agonizing Blast in terms of DPR. Use the Agonizing Blast row to match the -1CHA Heavy Crossbow.

Comment: Eldritch is easier to setup (less feats and invocations), comparable damage at most levels and can have utility from repelling blast, so most of the time I prefer that route.

But if you really want FULL DPR go Hand Crossbows instead, like someone suggested in another response. It's WAY better than heavy crossbow, except for the range of attack.

Answer (score 28):

### Spoiler: It's always *eldritch blast*.

Shooting twice per turn is always going to be superior to firing once per turn, unless the one shot is *vastly* better.  Like, not "add a stat bonus"-better, but like "this is literally a siege weapon"-better.

First off, comparing an Invocation-enhanced crossbow against an unmodified *eldritch blast* is obviously an unequal comparison. If you're going to throw Improved Pact Weapon into the mix in order to claim the higher stat bonus with your crossbow, you should compare that against an Agonizing Blast -- it's only fair to add an invocation to **both** sides of the comparison. And in that case, it's a quite simple "one attack versus two attacks" scenario.  With roughly equal chances to hit and roughly equivalent damage, two *blast* beams is of course superior to one crossbow bolt.  Even if though Improved Pact Weapon makes the crossbow count as a +1 weapon, a 5% hit rate increase and +1 damage can't come close to the benefit of just firing twice as often.

So let's ignore invocations: If we compare a standard crossbow attack to a standard *blast*, the *blast* is still the better option. You hit more often because of the higher attack bonus, *and* you get two attacks per turn rather than one, so you have a very high chance of hitting at least once.

The actual math would depend on what AC you're shooting against, but in general, you're talking about one attack at +5 for 1d10+2 damage versus two attacks at +7 for 1d10 damage each.

Supposing you're attacking a relatively tough AC 16, your crossbow will hit on an 11+, or 50%, which gives an average damage over time of (5.5+2)*0.5 = **3.75 damage per round**.

By comparison, your eldritch blasts would hit on a 9+, or 60% of the time, and deal 1d10 damage each. So over time that would average out to 5.5*0.6 = 3.3 damage per beam. Since you're firing twice per turn, your expected damage would be double that, or **6.6 damage per round**, which is vastly better than the crossbow. I ignored the impact of critical hits in the calculation here, but since you're making twice as many attack rolls with the *blast*, you'll crit twice as often, so that's only going to tip things even more towards *eldritch blast*.  (Point of interest: The break-even point on damage-dealt would be at a 30% hit-rate for the *blast*, which I believe in this case would mean blasting with a -1 charisma modifier.  Yes, the power of shooting twice is so great that the world's worst warlock is STILL a better, more consistent combatant than you with a crossbow.)

"Consistent" could be interpreted to mean "more likely to do at least some damage every turn" or "the maximum expected damage-per-round", but either way *eldritch blast* is the way to go for a warlock.

For what it's worth, the crossbow with Improved Pact Weapon is just barely competitive with an unenhanced *blast* at 5th level, at around 6.3 damage/round.  In order to make it superior, you need to spend a lot more resources (such as Thirsting Blade and the Crossbow Expert feat), and as you level up there are a lot more options that can make either method competitive -- good enough to be worthwhile if not "the best", at any rate.

If I had to guess, the point of Improved Pact Weapon isn't really to enable a crossbow- or shortbow-focused warlock, but rather to give a melee-focused warlock a ranged option that can leverage all the boosts he's pouring into his pact weapon.

Comment: It's entirely possible that my DPR calculation is slightly off, but given the vast difference between the two scenarios, I don't think it matters even if it is slightly wrong.

Comment: I agree with everything except your last  paragraph, the problem is not Improved Pact Weapon, its [crossbows](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134003/9552)

Comment: Why do you calculate with Dex instead of Cha for the crossbow?

Comment: @András I don't know what you mean by 'problem'.  I didn't say there's a problem with IPW. I'm just saying the ranged options it offers will never be as good as an *eldritch blast* as a primary focus; they're really good if you have focused on blade pact and want to leverage those invocations when you can't easily get into melee.  I doubt a shortbow-blade-lock would be able to keep up with a blast-lock, but I haven't worked the numbers up as that wasn't the question.

Comment: @András I used DEX in the calculation because a crossbow isn't fired with your CHA unless it's a pact weapon, which requires a specific invocation, in which case it should be compared to an enhanced *blast*, see paragraph 2 for discussion.

Answer (score 5):

## [Magical] Hand Crossbows are better at every level... Except level 11

If you truly want to maximize DPR, you'll pick up the *Crossbow Expert* feat, and then use a Magical *Hand Crossbow* with your Hexblade warlock. The reason for this is that starting at level 5, you'll get to make three attacks per turn with your lone Hand Crossbow: 2 from the *Thirsting Blade* invocation, and 1 from the Bonus Action permitted by your *Crossbow Expert* feat. This will offset the DPR of Agonizing Blast at [almost] every level, simply due to the high number of attacks.

\begin{array}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\text{} & \text{AC 0} & \text{AC 14} & \text{AC 16} & \text{AC 18} & \text{AC 20} & \text{AC 26}\\ \hline
\text{L5 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 20.500 & 16.300 & 14.200 & 12.100 & 10.000 & 3.700\\ \hline
\text{L5 Hand Crossbow x3} & 24.750 & 19.650 & 17.100 & 14.550 & 12.000 & 4.350\\ \hline
\text{L5 Agonizing Blast x2} & 18.600 & 13.850 & 11.950 & 10.050 & 8.150 & 2.450\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L8 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 22.400 & 18.950 & 16.650 & 14.350 & 12.050 & 5.150\\ \hline
\text{L8 Hand Crossbow x3} & 27.600 & 23.325 & 20.475 & 17.625 & 14.775 & 6.225\\ \hline
\text{L8 Agonizing Blast x2} & 20.500 & 16.300 & 14.200 & 12.100 & 10.000 & 3.700\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L9 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 22.400 & 20.100 & 17.800 & 15.500 & 13.200 & 6.300\\ \hline
\text{L9 Hand Crossbow x3} & 27.600 & 24.750 & 21.900 & 19.050 & 16.200 & 7.650\\ \hline
\text{L9 Agonizing Blast x2} & 20.500 & 17.350 & 15.250 & 13.150 & 11.050 & 4.750\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L11 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 22.400 & 20.100 & 17.800 & 15.500 & 13.200 & 6.300\\ \hline
\text{L11 Hand Crossbow x3} & 27.600 & 24.750 & 21.900 & 19.050 & 16.200 & 7.650\\ \hline
\text{L11 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 26.025 & 22.875 & 19.725 & 16.575 & 7.125\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L12 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 28.600 & 25.300 & 22.000 & 18.700 & 8.800\\ \hline
\text{L12 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 37.500 & 33.150 & 28.800 & 24.450 & 11.400\\ \hline
\text{L12 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 26.025 & 22.875 & 19.725 & 16.575 & 7.125\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L13 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 30.250 & 26.950 & 23.650 & 20.350 & 10.450\\ \hline
\text{L13 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 39.675 & 35.325 & 30.975 & 26.625 & 13.575\\ \hline
\text{L13 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 27.600 & 24.450 & 21.300 & 18.150 & 8.700\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L17 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 31.900 & 28.600 & 25.300 & 22.000 & 12.100\\ \hline
\text{L17 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 41.850 & 37.500 & 33.150 & 28.800 & 15.750\\ \hline
\text{L17 Agonizing Blast x4} & 41.000 & 38.900 & 34.700 & 30.500 & 26.300 & 13.700\\ \hline
\end{array}

<sup>[Detailed Statistical Analysis here](https://gist.github.com/Xirema/fd1016f820fd83bd203b31019d821f24)</sup>

Here are the breakpoints:

- At level 8, our Charisma hits 20
- At level 9, our proficiency goes up to +4
- At level 11, *Eldritch Blast* gets 3 attacks, and (briefly) becomes the top DPR.
- At level 12, we gain *Lifedrinker*, and the crossbows take over once again
- At level 13, our proficiency goes up to +5
- At level 17, our proficiency goes up to +6, and Eldritch Blast gets its fourth attack. Heavy Crossbows fall behind, but Hand Crossbows are still at the top

## TL; Too much Stats

So if you absolutely want to maximize DPR, use a Hand Crossbow with the following:

- FEAT: *Crossbow Expert*
- INVOCATION: *Thirsting Blade*
- ITEM: *Hand Crossbow +1/+2/+3* (non-magical Hand Crossbows cannot be used as Pact Weapons)
- INVOCATION: *Lifedrinker*

### "But I'm not a Variant Human!"

Use this table instead, where instead of taking the *Crossbow Expert* feat at level 1, you're instead forced to take it at level 4, meaning you don't reach 20 Charisma until level 12. The only difference is that below level 11, *Heavy Crossbows* are equivalent to *Agonizing Blast* in DPR.

\begin{array}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\text{} & \text{AC 0} & \text{AC 14} & \text{AC 16} & \text{AC 18} & \text{AC 20} & \text{AC 26}\\ \hline
\text{L5 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 18.600 & 13.850 & 11.950 & 10.050 & 8.150 & 2.450\\ \hline
\text{L5 Hand Crossbow x3} & 21.900 & 16.275 & 14.025 & 11.775 & 9.525 & 2.775\\ \hline
\text{L5 Agonizing Blast x2} & 18.600 & 13.850 & 11.950 & 10.050 & 8.150 & 2.450\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L8 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 20.500 & 16.300 & 14.200 & 12.100 & 10.000 & 3.700\\ \hline
\text{L8 Hand Crossbow x3} & 24.750 & 19.650 & 17.100 & 14.550 & 12.000 & 4.350\\ \hline
\text{L8 Agonizing Blast x2} & 20.500 & 16.300 & 14.200 & 12.100 & 10.000 & 3.700\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L9 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 20.500 & 17.350 & 15.250 & 13.150 & 11.050 & 4.750\\ \hline
\text{L9 Hand Crossbow x3} & 24.750 & 20.925 & 18.375 & 15.825 & 13.275 & 5.625\\ \hline
\text{L9 Agonizing Blast x2} & 20.500 & 17.350 & 15.250 & 13.150 & 11.050 & 4.750\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L11 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 20.500 & 17.350 & 15.250 & 13.150 & 11.050 & 4.750\\ \hline
\text{L11 Hand Crossbow x3} & 24.750 & 20.925 & 18.375 & 15.825 & 13.275 & 5.625\\ \hline
\text{L11 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 26.025 & 22.875 & 19.725 & 16.575 & 7.125\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L12 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 28.600 & 25.300 & 22.000 & 18.700 & 8.800\\ \hline
\text{L12 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 37.500 & 33.150 & 28.800 & 24.450 & 11.400\\ \hline
\text{L12 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 26.025 & 22.875 & 19.725 & 16.575 & 7.125\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L13 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 30.250 & 26.950 & 23.650 & 20.350 & 10.450\\ \hline
\text{L13 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 39.675 & 35.325 & 30.975 & 26.625 & 13.575\\ \hline
\text{L13 Agonizing Blast x3} & 30.750 & 27.600 & 24.450 & 21.300 & 18.150 & 8.700\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\text{L17 Heavy Crossbow x2} & 31.900 & 31.900 & 28.600 & 25.300 & 22.000 & 12.100\\ \hline
\text{L17 Hand Crossbow x3} & 41.850 & 41.850 & 37.500 & 33.150 & 28.800 & 15.750\\ \hline
\text{L17 Agonizing Blast x4} & 41.000 & 38.900 & 34.700 & 30.500 & 26.300 & 13.700\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Worth noting that this ignores the benefits of Hex.  The hand crossbow build constantly consumes your bonus actions.  The eldritch blast build doesn't, and can therefore use them to reposition the target for Hex, granting up to 1d6 extra damage per blast.

Comment: I know this is an old post but wanted to clarify one thing: you don't need a MAGICAL hand crossbow to use it with CHA bonus.

Hex Warrior says [...]Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls.[...]

The restrictions are that the weapon can't be 2Handed and you need to be proficient. Hand crossbows are NOT 2Handed and you get proficiency with martial weapons from Hex Warrior.

Comment: @BrunoPugliese The restriction on Hand Crossbows doesn't come from the Hex Warrior feature, it comes from the Pact of the Blade feature. That only allows you to summon melee weapons (or any Magical weapon of your choice), and Pact of the Blade is required for the Thirsting Blade feature, which allows a warlock to attack twice with their [pact] weapon when attacking. A hexblade warlock is fully capable of using a Hand Crossbow as their Hex Warrior weapon, but unless they also make it their Pact Weapon, they can't use the invocations to attack twice/add +cha again with Lifedrinker, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

## Eldritch Blast is stronger *at this point*

However, the right weapon with the right invocation could easily outperform it.

### Invocation

You can replace one of your existing invocations to Thirsting Blade, that gives an additional attack with your pact weapon, unless it has the loading property.

### Weapon

As outlined above, crossbows are not really good because of the loading property. You could fix this with Crossbow Expert, but the best benefit (an additional attack with hand crossbows) is inaccessible with Pact Weapons.

## Calculation after fixes

**Eldritch Blast:** 2 attacks for 1d10 = 11 damage.
**Heavy Crossbow with IPW:** 1 attack for 1d10+5 = 10.5.
**Longbow with IPW and Thirsing Blade:** 2 attacks for 1d8+5 = 19.

72% higher damage output for the Longbow than the previous winner EB, *and* +1 to hit.

Comment: Why is it not accessible with pact weapons?

Comment: @BenBarden You can't use a Hand Crossbow as a Pact Weapon unless it's already magical (+1/+2/+3/etc.), which means it's dependent on what your DM is willing to issue.